# Let $\Phi : R \rightarrow R'$ be a ring homomorphism, where $R,R'$ are rings with unity. Then which of these is true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\Phi : R \rightarrow R'$ be a ring homomorphism, where $R,R'$ are rings with unity. Then which of these is true :

$(i)~\Phi(1)=1 ~\forall~$ rings $R,R~'$ with unity

$(ii)~\Phi(1) \ne 1 $ for any rings $R,R~'$

$(iii)~ \Phi(1) \ne 1 $ if $R~'$ is an integral domain or if $\Phi$ is onto.

$(iv)~ \Phi(1) = 1 $ if $R~'$ is an integral domain or if $\Phi$ is onto.

**Attempt:**

$\Phi(1\cdot1)= [ \Phi(1)]^2 $

$\implies \Phi(1) [\Phi(1) - 1]=0$

Only when $R~'$ is an integral domain can we infer that the above statement means either $\Phi(1)=0$ or $\Phi(1)=1$

If $\Phi(1)=0,$ then $\Phi$ represents the trivial homomorphism as $\Phi(x) = \Phi(x) \Phi(1) = 0$.

Else, if $\Phi$ is onto and $R~'$ is an integral domain, then the only option for $\Phi(1)$ is being equal to $1$.

So, $(iv)$ should be the right option.

Could someone please confirm if I am right?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A ring homomorphism of rings with unity is usually required to send $1$ to $1$. But if that is not part of your definition then it need indeed not hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem with *(i)*:

Suppose $R' = R = \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$, with component-wise addition and multiplication and:

$\Phi((a,b)) = (a,0)$. We have:

$\Phi((a,b) + (a',b')) = \Phi((a+a',b+b'))$

$ = (a+a',0) = (a,0) + (a',0) = \Phi((a,b)) + \Phi((a',b'))$

and: $\Phi((a,b)(a',b')) = \Phi((aa',bb')) = (aa',0) = (a,0)(a',0) = \Phi((a,b))\Phi((a',b'))$,

but $\Phi((1,1)) = (1,0)$ is not the multiplicative identity of $R$ (although it *is* the multiplicative identity of $\Phi(R)$).

Comment: Yeah, that means (iv) is more convincing?

Comment: You might try proving it is true.